# TextView save resource ID when setting text

Tags: java, android, reflection, textview

Originally I want to create a library to easily change locale without having to recreate activity for changes to take effect.
For that purpose I want to store the `resId` of `setText(int resId)` method in a variable to re-set text by this ID from another locale.

The problem is that `setText(int resId)` is `final` in a TextVIew.

So my question is if there is a way to override final method (i think no), or add some hook so I'll be able to get this `resId` whenever this method will be called?

**Let me also add what I've tried:**

First I thought about using an `InvocationHandler`, so I could create an instance of a `TextView` as a field of my class, and pass all the calls to it except `setText`. But Unfortunately I can't return anything in the constructor.
Then I've thought about implementing a Decorator Pattern by creating a class, which extends `View`, and has all the methods, which a `TextView` has, and creating  an instance of a `TextView` as a field of my class, and same way passing all methods calls to it, but it should not work for 2 reasons:

1. methods, which require an instance of a `TextView` won't work, as my class won't extend a TextView
2. TextView's implementation is 11969 lines long, and it would take hell of a time to copy all methods.